When do we need to use a dot prefix when doing lit template attribute property assignments for html elements?
The lit documentation has the following example showing how to set attribute values:
<!-- attribute values -->
<div label=${label}></div>
<button ?disabled=${isDisabled}>Click me!</button>
<input .value=${currentValue}>
<button @click=${this.handleClick()}>

So in the above example label is set without a dot prefix, but value uses a dot prefix (.value).
When do we need to include a dot . prefix when working with html elements in our lit element templates.  Is it only for value property assignments?

Read the fine manual - dot means property, not just attribute.

It's an property not an attribute, you mostly would use this to provide a larger data set like an Object or an Array of Objects.
Things that cannot be a simple string should be provided using a property like .value or whatever name you choose

how do we know that it's .value for input elements but no dot (label=${label}>) for div elements?  For actual lit elements I understand that it's always .propertyName when setting properties, so I'm just trying to understand the semantics when working with attributes for non custom elements?

That makes sense, however Lit examples show that the value property on input elements can be set using the dot prefix html<input .value=${this.itemCount}>; ...

You are right, that was a bad example on my end. That is not true in this particular case but would be for any custom element.

The only example I've seen for normal html elements like input is the value example that uses the dot prefix, so I was just curious if that is the only case where it should be used... or if there is some characteristic of normal html elements that would inform us when we should use a dot prefix to set attributes?
